# MVC HttpContext.Current.Cache get random object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext.cache

How can I get a random object from the cache?
What I really want is to get a different object each time I access the cache, but a random object is also good.

Comment: Put an object in the cache that has a property or method that returns a random object (or whatever your requirement demands)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have strings in my db. I load the strings to the cache. every string has an expiration date, and when it expires, my callback (which gets called when the string expires) replaces the string with a new one, that has a new expiration date. I want to get a different string every time I ask an object from the cache. I also add strings to the db (and to the cache) when I find new strings.

Comment: You're putting a string into cache but want to get a different string when you retrieve it? Or what?

Comment: No. let's say I put 100 string objects in the cache. So I have 100 key value pairs in the cache. Now I want to access the objects in the cache, and I want to get a different object every time I access the cache.